# Finding duplicated images

Tags: image, image-processing

I want to write a C program, on Windows, that is able to detect duplicated images. I meet the following problems:

1-Even if an image has the same Width and Height, the compression (in case of jpeg) is different and the colors too.

2-Two image may look similar but have a different size.

3-One image has been saved in jpeg and the other in bmp or png.

4-Points 1 to 3 all together.

I don't see a solution. I read that images could be resized, without respecting proportion, 128x128 and one have to compare this new one. Results are not good.

Could someone help me, please ?

Comment: It is not clear whether your requirements are inclusive or exclusive? Do you want to match those difference or exclude them?

Comment: If you want to include these differences as being the same image, then you need to look into perceptual hashes such as block mean hash, or difference hash. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing.  ImageMagick has a compare metric of phash. See https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/ and https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=24906, where it links to http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/perceptual_hash_test_results_510/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post a comment but I don't have enough reputation to.

There is a program called ImageMagick that can convert and compare images (as well as several other things).  The compare feature of ImageMagick can be used to generate an image with red pixels where it found differences and white pixels where it didn't.

Maybe you could use ImageMagick to generate an image with the differences highlighted and then use this image in your C program to see if the number of differences is great enough for you to consider it a different image.

ImageMagick can be found at: https://imagemagick.org/

The compare command is talked about here: https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have read many things above perceptuals hashes. I will take a look at ImageMagick.